# WordPress: How to pass “Blog pages show at most” value into shortcode inside a template

Tags: wordpress

I’m using Ajax Load More plugin inside a custom WordPress theme by inserting a shortcode into my index.php template.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="10" offset="10" pause="true" scroll="false"]'); }?>
```

Is there a way to get the value of “Blog pages show at most” from Settings/Reading and pass it into the shortcode to automatically update its posts_per_page and offset values when “Blog pages show at most” value is changed inside the dashboard?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, so I'll post it here if anyone else ever needs it.

```
$default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
```

gets the number of posts set inside Settings/Reading.

Then simply add the variable into shortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="'.$default_posts_per_page.'" offset="'.$default_posts_per_page.'" pause="true" scroll="false"]');
```